# Pandas, Pivot table from 2 columns with values being a count of one of those columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
+---------------+-------------+
| Test_Category | Test_Result |
+---------------+-------------+
| Cat_1         | Pass        |
| Cat_1         | N/A         |
| Cat_2         | Fail        |
| Cat_2         | Fail        |
| Cat_3         | Pass        |
| Cat_3         | Pass        |
| Cat_3         | Fail        |
| Cat_3         | N/A         |
+---------------+-------------+
```

I need a table like this:

```
+------+------+------+-----+
|      | Pass | Fail | N/A |
+------+------+------+-----+
| Cat1 |    1 |      |   1 |
| Cat2 |      |    2 |     |
| Cat3 |    2 |    1 |   1 |
+------+------+------+-----+
```

I tried using a Pivot, but can't figure out how to make it count occurrences from Test_Result column and put them as values into pivot result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is problem `NaN` values are exluded, so necessary use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Test_Category'], df['Test_Result'].fillna('n/a'))
print (df1)
Test_Result    Fail  Pass  n/a
Test_Category                 
Cat_1             0     1    1
Cat_2             2     0    0
Cat_3             1     2    1
```

Or use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df['Test_Result'] = df['Test_Result'].fillna('n/a')

df1 = df.groupby(['Test_Category','Test_Result']).size().unstack()
print (df1)
Test_Result    Fail  Pass  n/a
Test_Category                 
Cat_1           NaN   1.0  1.0
Cat_2           2.0   NaN  NaN
Cat_3           1.0   2.0  1.0
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Test_Category','Test_Result']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Test_Result    Fail  Pass  n/a
Test_Category                 
Cat_1             0     1    1
Cat_2             2     0    0
Cat_3             1     2    1
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Test_Category',columns='Test_Result', aggfunc='size')
```

Comment: Thank you. The solutions that have .fill('N/A') worked for me, the other ones that don't have that part, return only 2 columns "Fail" and "Pass" in resulting dataframe.    
Tried with 'N/A' and 'NA' values and it seems by default those are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a new dataframe using unique values in the two columns as indices and columns, and use pandas' `iterrows()`

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(index=df['Test_Category'].unique().tolist(), columns=df['Test_Result'].unique().tolist())

for index, row in df_out.iterrows():
    for col in df_out.columns:
        df_out.loc[index, col] = len(df[(df['Test_Category'] == index) & (df['Test_Result'] == col)])
```

**Output**:

```
       Pass  nan  Fail
Cat1     1    1     0
Cat2     0    0     2
Cat3     2    1     1
```

Although using `groupby()` should definitely be faster.